# Unable to run protoc in virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am trying to train a tensorflow pretrained model with some data. I have created a virtual environment to manage the versions of libraries properly. However, I am unable to run the 'protoc' command in the virtual environment. It runs fine outside the virtual environment as I have already added the protoc.exe file to path.
This is the error I get :

```
(environment_3_9_7) PS C:\Users\dipes\Desktop\Computer Vision\Computer Vision Assignment> protoc
protoc : The term 'protoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was   
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ protoc
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (protoc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to add the protoc.exe to the path of virtualenv ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pasting the protoc.exe file in the /Scripts of the virtual environment solved the issue for me.